# Inconsistent type for JavaScript ES6 template strings

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, template-strings

While testing JavaScript ES6's new template strings (in Firefox, if it matters), I noticed some inconsistencies in their types.

I defined a custom function, like this:

```
function f(a) {
    console.log(typeof(a));
    console.log(a);
}
```

First, I tested the function "normally", using parentheses around the template string.

```
f(`Hello, World!`)
```

As expected, this yielded a type of `string` and `Hello, World!` was outputted to the console.

Then I called the function shorthand, without the parentheses, and inconsistencies occurred.

```
f`Hello, World!`
```

The type became `object`, and `Array [ "Hello, World!" ]` was outputted to the console.

Why was the template string wrapped in an array when using the second method? Is this just a bug in Firefox (ES6 *is* a new standard, after all) or is this behavior expected for some reason?

Comment: Try `console.log\`a ${1} b ${2} c\`;` to understand better what's happening. By omitting the parenthesis, you've completely change the meaning of your statement: you're not simply calling the function any more, but you're using a *tagged template*. Yep, this syntax sucks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// A function call, passed the result of a template literal.
f(`str`)
```

and

```
// A tagged template call, passed metadata about a template.
f`str`
```

are not the same. The first calls `f` with single string as an argument. The second calls `f` with several parameters, depending on the template. e.g.

```
f`one${2}three${4}five`
```

would pass `f`

```
f(strings, ...values)
```

with

```
strings
// ['one', 'three', 'five']
```

which is a list of all of the string sections of the template, and

```
values
// [2, 4]
```

which are all of the values that fit between the strings. This allows tags to preprocess the string and process it.

The [documentation on MDN can help more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings#Tagged_template_strings).

Comment: From a 36k rep users, I'd expected at list a link to the specification. A bit disappointed.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've suggested an edit to add that this syntax is called tagged template strings, as I've learned from @Blackhole's comment, to help future searchers. This answer was helpful and informative.

Comment: @UndefinedFunction: It's called "tagged template" (no "string").  I think it's a bit misleading to call the "strings" (official they are called "tagged template" and "template literal"), especially since tagged templates don't necessarily result in strings at all.

Comment: @FelixKling hmmm, interesting. The MDN said "tagged template strings", so that's why I called them that.

Comment: @UndefinedFunction: Yep. I'm not particular happy about that ;) http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-tagged-templates

Comment: @FelixKling well, guess you can't beat the language spec!

Comment: @Blackhole The spec isn't particularly easy to read for these, I didn't think it would help.

Comment: @UndefinedFunction I made an edit to mention the names, but as Felix said, "template string" isn't the best name :)

Comment: @loganfsmyth True. Perhaps you'd like to update your link to point directly [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings#Tagged_template_strings)  (jumps to relevant portion of the page). Your answer addresses the topic nicely though, good job!